# Parsing variables inside json - python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, api, parsing

I am trying to include variables inside string format before loading it to json and trigger post request.

```
import json

def addRecord(TransactionID, Date, Status, Reference):
    data =  """
        {
            "fields":{
                "TransactionID": TransactionID,
                "Date": Date,
                "Status": Status,
                "Reference": Reference
            }
        }"""
    data = json.loads(data)
```

**Right side are variables passed to the function**

I am getting an error that I am not sending any value in json

```
(env) myusername@mylaptop:/mnt/c/Users/myuser/projects/scripts/myproject$ python3 main.py
        {
            "fields":{
                "TransactionID": TransactionID,
                "Date": Date,
                "Status": Status,
                "Reference": Reference
            }
        }
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/c/Users/yalat/projects/scripts/apiCall/main.py", line 33, in <module>
    print(addRecord(5123, 20211009, "added", 12))
  File "/mnt/c/Users/yalat/projects/scripts/apiCall/main.py", line 29, in addRecord
    data = json.loads(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 4 column 34 (char 67)
```

Comment: Did you mean to use an [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals) to format the string? As written, the string includes the literal names of the variables, not there contents.

Comment: See Transaction ID, Status, Date and reference. I am not able to pass it as variables. It got pass as a string

Answer (score 1):

Use `f-string`. It provides a way to embed expressions inside string literals

```py
data =  f"""
        {
            "fields":{
                "TransactionID": {TransactionID},
                "Date": {Date},
                "Status": {Status},
                "Reference": {Reference}
            }
        }"""
data = json.loads(data)
```

Comment: I am not sure if I can parse a dictionary as `json.load(data)` require it to be string.
See the following error
`TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or byte array, not dict`

As for the f-string. It didn't work. Error I am getting is that string is too nested to be loaded
`SyntaxError: f-string: expressions nested too deeply`

Comment: Here is the API I am trying to hit (POST request)
`curl -v -X POST https://api.airtable.com/v0/tableID/table\
  -H "Authorization: Bearer YOUR_API_KEY" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --data '{
  "fields": {
    "TransactionID": 15228,
    "Date": 20141018,
    "Status": "Transferred",
    "Reference": 55289
  }
}'`

Comment: the nesting error means that you probably have an f string inside an f string

Comment: check your code